# В чем проблема не корректного исполнения запроса ROOM?

Tags: java, android, android-room

Документацию ,примеры прочел, решил опробовать ROOM, на вид просто и удобно, но где-то видимо допустил ошибку. Подскажите, в чем я не прав?

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "Stages")
public class Stages {

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   public int ID;
   public String DESC;
}
```

DAO

```
@Dao
public interface StagesDAO {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM stages")
   List<Stages> getStages();

   @Insert
   void insert (Stages stages);

   @Query("DELETE FROM stages WHERE ID = :id")
   void remove(int id);
}
```

MainActivity

```
Log.d("read",String.valueOf(stagesDB.stagesDAO().getStages()));
```

В результате выводиться не текст, который находится в базе, а какое-то шифрование:

2022-10-10 19:28:13.149 9408-9408/com.eshbaht.room_one D/read: [com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@9d343e6, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@7882d27, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@5e74bd4, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@68e117d, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@77fb872, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@5c074c3, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@8575140, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@f6f4879, com.eshbaht.room_one.DataBase.Stages@10ce9be]

Comment: Это не шифрование, а стандартный вывод метода `Object.toString()`. Переопределите его в своём `Stages` и верните строку, которую хотите видеть в логе.

Comment: Оставьте  нормальный ответ, отмечу решением)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не шифрование, а стандартный вывод метода `Object.toString()`.
Переопределите его в своём `Stages` и верните строку, которую хотите видеть в логе.

```java
@Entity(tableName = "Stages")
public class Stages {

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   public int ID;
   public String DESC;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return DESC;
   }
}
```